# Strange error with mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a strange error with my mod_rewrite.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

When i type into my adress bar:

```
localhost/test/1/2
```

And in my index.php file i have:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

What i should expect to see is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => test
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
)
```

But the result i get is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => index.php
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
)
```

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If-Then-Else Logic, Mutually Exclusive (and Final) Rules**

There are several problems.

- `In mod-rewrite`, one set of conditions applies to one rule only. But here you are trying to apply them to multiple rules.
- Your rules are not mutually exclusive. The `.*` matches all characters, so it can match all three patterns. We need more specific rules.
- Your rules are not final (`L` flag needed).

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# IF: Does the file or folder exist?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# THEN leave unchanged, skip 3 rules
RewriteRule ^ - [L,S=3]

# ELSE (the file or folder does not exist)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]

# FINALLY: leave unchanged
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: It returns only: Array ( [a] => index.php )

Comment: So the answer helped, or you did something else? If it solved it, please click the checkmark on the left to accept the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear it helped! According to the iron laws of SO etiquette, I'm also allowed to [tell someone who has never upvoted an answer about how it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/). :) If this or another answer helps, would you consider clicking the Up arrow above the checkmark to the left of the answer to promote it? That's how the reputation system works here. Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava Thank you and FYI I'm having a little dance, it's the first time one of my answers with `SKIP` is accepted. I've been wanting to make that IF-THEN-ELSE logic work for a while but as you know there can always be other issues preventing a solution from working. :) I have a feeling the `FINALLY` line is unneeded, but I didn't want the risk of crashing by skipping to a non-existing rule.

Comment: Hey Yooouuri, if you have time, can you please try the solution without the last two lines (from `# FINALLY:` to the end)? I put it in for safety because the `mod-rewrite` documentation doesn't specify whether it's allowed to skip to a place where there are no more rules, but I have a feeling it will work. If you do try, please let me know the result. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes `# FINALLY` rule is definitely not needed :)